# How to measure the quality of a research idea?

Tags: research-process, research-topic

I am at the start of my PhD. For the last four months, I have been studying the existing literature on the topic given to me by my advisor.

I want to know, how do I find a research idea on which I can publish a paper?
How to judge beforehand if this particular idea can lead to a research paper or not?

Comment: Related/Duplictes: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117/how-to-find-a-good-topic-for-a-phd-research-proposal, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27086/is-there-any-systematic-approach-to-select-find-a-research-topic

Comment: Related/Duplicates https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103636/how-to-find-research-topics-and-publish-more, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21700/how-to-find-relevant-and-new-open-research-topics

Comment: Ask your supervisor! (if it is possible)

Comment: Maybe a frame challenge, maybe not. Does the question "glimmer" for you? That is, do you find it exciting? If it's "the same-old same-old" then maybe you should be adjusting.

Comment: In some ways, that's the whole point of earning a PhD.